# Blank page Sqoop in Hue, "error : could not get connectors"

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, hue, sqoop2

I'm trying to use sqoop in Hue but there's an error :

> Sqoop error: Could not get connectors.

and no sqoop wizard in page. 
But I could import data from Oracle using sqoop shell (not sqoop2).

My questions are :

- Is there anything else to config beside putting oracle jdbc driver ? (in /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.0-1.cdh5.5.0.p0.8/lib/sqoop2/client-lib/)
- What directories that needs to be permitted for user sqoop2 ? (except /var/lib/sqoop )

**note** : I still got no clue after reading this post [https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Web-UI-Hue-Beeswax/Blank-Sqoop-page-in-Hue-2-5-0/td-p/2581](http://Blank%20Sqoop%20page%20in%20Hue%202.5.0)

**env** : Hue 3.9 / Sqoop2 / CDH 5.5.0 / CM 5.5.0 / LDAP, Kerberos & Sentry installed

Comment: Did you configure Sqoop2 properly? http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/cdh_ig_sqoop2_configure.html